# How to show the following assertion?

Tags: functional-analysis

We know that we have $[\int |f(x)|^{p} \mu(dx)]^{1/p}\leq [\int |f(x)|^{q} \mu(dx)]^{1/q}$ when $p\leq q$, where $\mu$ is a finite measure and $f$ is a smooth function. How about for the following inequality:

$[\int \left(|f(x)|^{p} + \sum_{i=1}^n |f^{(i)}(x)|^{p} \right)\mu(dx)]^{1/p}\leq [\int \left(|f(x)|^{q} + \sum_{i=1}^n |f^{(i)}(x)|^{q}\right) \mu(dx)]^{1/q}$

I suspect that if $\mu$ is a measure such that $\int \mu(dx)=1$, it is true. How to show my assertion? Would someone give hints on it?

Comment: Sobolev Spaces, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space

Answer (score 0):

By Hölders inequality for $1\leq p\leq q <\infty$ we have

$\int |f^{j}(x)|^p\mu (dx)\leq(\int |f^{j}(x)|^q\mu(dx))^{\frac{p}{q}}(\int \mu(dx))^{1-\frac{p}{q}} $ for every $j=0,...,n$.

Thus if $\int \mu(dx)=1$

$(\sum_{j=0}^n\int |f^{(j)}(x)|^p\mu(dx))^{\frac{1}{p}}$

$\leq(\sum_{j=0}^n(\int |f^{j}(x)|^q\mu(dx))^{\frac{p}{q}})^{\frac{1}{p}}$

$=((n+1)\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{1}{n+1}(\int |f^{j}(x)|^q\mu(dx))^{\frac{p}{q}})^{\frac{1}{p}}$

$\leq (n+1)^{\frac{1}{p}}(\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{1}{n+1}\int |f^{(j)}(x)|^q\mu(dx))^{\frac{1}{q}}=(n+1)^{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}}(\sum_{j=0}^n\int |f^{(j)}(x)|^q\mu(dx))^{\frac{1}{q}}$

where we used that $x\rightarrow x^{\frac {p}{q}}$ is concave for $p\leq q$.
I don´t see how to get rid of $(n+1)^{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}}$, though.